# how capture image or choose image file from web browser using js

Tags: javascript, html, webcam-capture

i'm trying to capture image or upload an existing image to my website , when i take the picture from my laptops webcam selected automatically , im trying several ways but none of them works , just wants to choose files

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
<!-- and this one -->
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<input type='file' id="imgInp" />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

they are not work , i try it in google chrome browser but shows nothing ?!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images

Comment: Copy-pasted from the link above --> Warning: Direct access to the camera is a powerful feature. It requires consent from the user, and your site MUST be on a secure origin (HTTPS).

Comment: its not https , and on linux server

Comment: @DanielF is it work if not https

Comment: @DanielF capture button works as submit button i dont want to submit it after capturing